# API route not found on NextJS 14 (App/route)

Tags: next.js, google-analytics-api, next.js13, swr

I want to use the Google Analytics API using SWR on Next.js 1,  however the route returns 404.

```
const { data: visitors } = useSWR("/api/dash/route", fetcher);
```

My folders tree:

[image]

app/analytics/page.tsx

```
"use client";
import useSWR from "swr";
import fetcher from "@lib/fetcher";

export default function Analytics() {
  const { data: visitors } = useSWR("/api/dash/route", fetcher);
  return (
      <div>{visitors?.totalVisitors} {visitors?.days} days</div>
  );
}
```

src/app/api/dash/route.ts

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import { BetaAnalyticsDataClient } from "@google-analytics/data";

const propertyId = process.env.GA_PROPERTY_ID;
const DAYS = 7;

const analyticsDataClient = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient({
  credentials: {
    client_email: process.env.GA_CLIENT_EMAIL,
    private_key: process.env.GA_PRIVATE_KEY?.replace(/\n/gm, '\n'),
  },
});

export default async function handler(
  _req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  const [response] = await analyticsDataClient.runReport({
    property: `properties/${propertyId}`,
    dateRanges: [
      {
        startDate: `${DAYS}daysAgo`,
        endDate: "today",
      },
    ],
    dimensions: [
      {
        name: "year",
      },
    ],
    metrics: [
      {
        name: "activeUsers",
      },
    ],
  });

  let totalVisitors = 0;
  response.rows?.forEach((row: any) => {
    totalVisitors += parseInt(row.metricValues[0].value);
  });

  res.setHeader(
    "Cache-Control",
    "public, s-maxage=43200, stale-while-revalidate=21600"
  );

  return res.status(200).json({
    totalVisitors,
    days: 7,
  });
}
```

I've tried everything:

- Change name to "route.ts" / "ga.ts" / "route.js"
- I've already tried putting "api/route.ts" in the path
- I've already tried calling the api with "http://localhost:3000/api/dash/route", "/api/dash/route", "api/dash/route", "./api/dash/route"
- use the code on components

On browser console:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Instead of making a request to `http://localhost:3000/api/dash/route` make a request to `http://localhost:3000/api/dash`

**Don't change the file structure**.

Check [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/nice-lake-mq6j6r?file=%2Fapp%2Fapi%2Fdash%2Froute.ts%3A8%2C1&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloojryqc0009356kzpe1nszt%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloojryqb0003356kaxoo3ks6%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloojryqb0006356k7o8x2s33%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloojryqc0008356k6xvwpfhm%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cloojryqb0003356kaxoo3ks6%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloojryqb0003356kaxoo3ks6%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cloojslv1007b356ku606ppli%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fapp%252Fapi%252Fdash%252Froute.ts%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloojslv1007b356ku606ppli%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522cloojryqc0008356k6xvwpfhm%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloojryqc0007356kzhjb5lfs%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252Fapi%252Fdash%252Froute%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloojryqc0008356k6xvwpfhm%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cloojryqc0007356kzhjb5lfs%2522%257D%252C%2522cloojryqb0006356k7o8x2s33%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloojryqb0004356kpz7h72ia%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloojryqb0005356kkubvytst%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522install%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cloojryqb0006356k7o8x2s33%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cloojryqb0004356kpz7h72ia%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) and try to hit the `api/dash` route.

Comment: That really was it!
Now the APIs are reading, but error 405 occurs (Method Not Allowed). but the problem of the question has been answered